# How to fix error no such module for import linphone sdk macos

Tags: ios, swift, linphone, linphone-sdk

I installed linphone sdk osx using Pods With the following command in the Pod file

```
pod 'linphone-sdk', '5.0.69', :source => ‘https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec-macos.git'
```

After executing command pod install and installing successfully
Gives this error for `import linphonesw`

> No such module 'linphonesw'

[image]

Comment: i used this code https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk/-/commit/18cd2436eda9cb72023c4727691e4a2b764966d3 and now "import linphonesw" dont show No such module 'linphonesw' error but in LinphoneWrapper.swift file "import linphone" show No such module 'linphone' any idea ?

Comment: i used this code https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk/-/commit/18cd2436eda9cb72023c4727691e4a2b764966d3 and now "import linphonesw" dont show No such module 'linphonesw' error but in LinphoneWrapper.swift file "import linphone" show No such module 'linphone' any idea ?

Comment: i used this code https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk/-/commit/18cd2436eda9cb72023c4727691e4a2b764966d3 and now "import linphonesw" dont show No such module 'linphonesw' error but in LinphoneWrapper.swift file "import linphone" show No such module 'linphone' any idea ?

Comment: i used this code https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk/-/commit/18cd2436eda9cb72023c4727691e4a2b764966d3 and now "import linphonesw" dont show No such module 'linphonesw' error but in LinphoneWrapper.swift file "import linphone" show No such module 'linphone' any idea ?

Comment: Has anyone had this problem?